# Threading a recursive function

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I have this recursive function that finds hrefs on a URL and adds them all to a global list.  This is done synchronously and takes a long time.  I have tried to do this with threading but have failed to get all threads to write to the one list.  Could someone please show me how to do this with threading?

```
private static void buildList (String BaseURL, String base){
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BaseURL).get();
        org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("a");
        for(Element e: links){
            //only if this website has no longer been visited
            if(!urls.contains(e.attr("abs:href"))){
                //eliminates pictures and pdfs
                if(!e.attr("abs:href").contains(".jpg")){
                    if(!e.attr("abs:href").contains("#")){
                        if(!e.attr("abs:href").contains(".pdf")){
                            //makes sure it doesn't leave the website
                            if(e.attr("abs:href").contains(base)){
                                urls.add(e.attr("abs:href"));
                                System.out.println(e.attr("abs:href"));

                                //recursive call
                                buildList(e.attr("abs:href"),base);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {

    }

    //to print out all urls.

    /*      
     * for(int i=0;i<urls.size();i++){
     * System.out.println(urls.get(i));
     * }
     */
}
```

Comment: Where is your threading code?

Comment: @redFIVE I did it as Runnable originally.  Due to other external factors Runnable extension would not be an acceptable solution.  I don't have experience multithreading in other ways hence the question.

Comment: have you even bothered trying to google Inter-thread communication methods?

Comment: @redFIVE if you don't want to help that is fine please just leave me alone.  I have been trying various things.  This is a state where I know it's functional and I wanted help from here.

Comment: I just helped by telling you EXACTLY what to search for to help yourself. If you don't want to help yourself, then why should others wants to hold your hand? I mean you still haven't even included what you tried with your threading....

Comment: @redFIVE Though I agree that OP could probably do a little more research, there's no reason to get all snarky and aggressive. If you don't like the question, just downvote it, flag if you think it's necessary, and move on.

Comment: @NikG Sorry next time I'll apply sunshine and lollipops to how I type...

Comment: @redFIVE look if you don't want to help that is fine it's voluntary.  I am a Ada programmer it's rare I touch Java.  You aren't being helpful this doesn't answer a large part of the question about thread safe lists.  Anyways I will get help from someone else.  Your tone is degrading and negative, if you continue I will report you.

Comment: Your code is not recursive in any way. It’s just inefficient. Just look how often you call `attr("abs:href")` on the same object, for example. Besides that, I doubt that there are so many links that this becomes relevant. I guess you are mistaking the (network) transfer time for the processing time.

Comment: @Holger it is recursive as the function calls itself this is the definition of recursion.  Also due to the nature of the situation transfer time is not a major issue.  The pre-created map of the site we are running this on shows upwards of 321 million pages, so yes, there are enough links

Comment: You’re right, that code is polluted with the unnecessarily nested `if`s that I overlooked the actual recursion inside. Before trying multiple threads you should just try to add the URLs to a set or queue and *complete* one document before traversing the next one. That would help cleaning up the resources and improve the performance a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great use case for [ForkJoin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). It'll provide *excellent* concurrency with very simple code.

For the set of urls parsed, use a `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());`.

You can also create a larger `ForkJoinPool` than the amount of cores you have, since there's network involved (the common usage expects that each thread will be performing work at ~100%).

Comment: I am a little confused on the Join part.  Do I actually need to Join threads in Java?  Each thread has no dependency on the other and it will end when it runs out of URLs to explore.  Can I fork without worrying about joining?

Comment: You want to gather the results. That's where the join part comes in.

Comment: see this is the problem I want different threads to remove options for other threads as they rule them out.  The List needs to be updated in real time by all threads as it runs.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You'll want to use a `Set` instead of `List` though.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of collection from concurrent package to store the values you get from different threads. ArrayBloac

You can use fork and join once you break you your problem into divide and conquer algo.